# Use Handlebars JS inside Fabricator JS Project

Tags: javascript, frameworks, handlebars.js, fabricator

I would like to use Handlebars JS in my Fabricator JS project.

I had already developed the project with handlebars as a stand alone solution and finished it functionally.

When I install it in Fabricator I get a blank page and my handlebars `{{}}` tags are empty. Does anyone know how to use these two plug-ins together?

HTML:

```
<div class="output-div"></div>

<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="my-template">
{{#header}}
  <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-priority="persist">{{title}}</th>
  <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-priority="2">{{type}}</th>
  <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-priority="3">{{date}}</th>
  <th scope="col" data-tablesaw-priority="4">{{dateExpired}}</th>
{{/header}}
</script>
```

json file:

```
{
  "header": [
  {
  "title": "Titel",
  "type": "Typ",
  "date": "Erstellung",
  "dateExpired": "Gueltig bis"
  }
 ]
}
```

JS:

```
source = $('#my-template').html();
template = Handlebars.compile(source)(json_data);
$('.output-div').append(template);
```

the variable (json_data) is the ajax object with the json data inside.
This example is functional without fabricator but inside fabricator no ouput is shown.

Fabricator: http://fbrctr.github.io/
Handlebars: http://handlebarsjs.com

Comment: Could you please share more info including your code and rendered output?

Comment: @GibinEalias ive update my question, thanks.